# Framework Java para Site estilo Ecommerce

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee, java

boa noite!

Gostaria da opinião de quem está na ativa sobre qual o framework mais indicado para desenvolvimento de um site no estilo E-commerce usando java.

Estava pensando em JSF 2 + Primefaces mas acredito que o JSF seja mais voltado para aplicações corporativas, até mesmo pelo fato de como as URLs ficam estranhas.

Alguém recomenda algum? Alguém também conhece algum site que foi desenvolvido utilizando algum framework do Java?

Obrigado!

Comment: O submarino e americanas foram desenvolvidos utilizando JSF 1.2? Alguém sabe dizer?

Answer (score 1):

Teste o shopizer: http://www.shopizer.com/#!/

Ele vem com umas features bem bacanas, como:

- Catalogo de produtos
- Carrinho de compras
- Revisão de pedido
- Configuração de pagamentos
- Configurações de entrega